# PivotTables Won't Update excel vba

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

What am I missing?!

I've got a workbook set up with a link to an external csv file. There are then some formulas which link to the values in the pivot table. if you've got the doc open and refresh it manually/wait the values in the pivot tables/formulas all update, but programmatically they stay the same (both the pivot and the resultant formulas)?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(filepath, True)

For Each pt In wbk.PivotTables
    pt.RefreshTable
Next pt

 wbk.Worksheets.Application.Calculate
```

Am I using the wrong kind of refresh? I tried adding in a wait time, but it did nothing. Calculations are set to automatic. Should I be refreshing the pivot data source rather than the tables themselves??

Comment: are the SourceRanges for each PivotTable changes ?

Comment: That code would never run since a `Workbook` object doesn't have a `PivotTables` property. You need to loop through `wbk.PivotCaches` and `Refresh` each one.